# Determine the Big O Notation:

Tags: algorithm, big-o, logarithm

5n^5/2 + n^2/5

I tried eliminating the lower order terms and coefficients, not producing a correct answer.

Not sure if I should use logs?

Comment: Usually you would consider only the `n^5`, as this is the most relevant part.

Comment: Maybe you should have posted it in [some other community](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking. ```O(n!)``` is always a valid answer (except for crazy Ackermann-functions and co.) as it bounds from above. Just get the definition and insert the right constants. This will also work for ```n^5``` which is the slowest-growing function according to big-O notation. Why would you use logs? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `f(n) = (5n^5)/2 + (n^2)/5 = (5/2)*n^5 + (1/5)*n^2`

The Big O notation for `f(n)` can be derived from the following simplification rules:

- If `f(n)` is a sum of several terms, we keep only the one with largest growth rate.
- If `f(n)` is a product of several factors, any constant is omitted.

From rule 1, `f(n)` is a sum of two terms, the one with largest growth rate is the one with the largest exponent as a function of `n`, that is: `(5/2)*n^5`

From rule 2, `(5/2)` is a constant in `(5/2)*n^5` because it does not depend on `n`, so it is omitted.

Then: `f(n) is O(n^5)`

Hope this helps. Check [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)